# Folder shortcuts from windows stops working

Tags: xubuntu, filesystem

I dual boot xubuntu alongside windows separated by two partitions. Every time I make a shortcut to a folder from the windows partition, it stops working/disappears from the side pane after restart. Is there any fix to this?

Comment: You're probably not automounting the windows partition. Is a dupe, let me look up...

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the right answer, it really is a dupe.  I'll delete it now.

Comment: @TestRains, there's no need to delete a duplicate. It will just be closed against the original question but remain as a signpost. So even a question closed as a duplicate has utility.

Comment: [Duplicate question etiquette: to delete or not to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230/468333)

Comment: This question will not be deleted just because it's a duplicate.